# Quais as diferenças entre as formas de manipular strings enormes com Python?

Tags: python, string

Quando é necessário trabalhar com *strings* muito grandes é normal vermos abordagens que buscam otimizar o processo de alguma forma. Das abordagens que já vi são utilizando:

1. `io.StringIO` ou `io.BytesIO`
2. `tempfile.TemporaryFile`
3. `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`
4. `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`

As quatro formas são objetos *file-like* e podem ser utilizados junto a um gerenciador de contexto.

```
with io.StringIO() as stream:
  ...

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as stream:
  ...

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile as stream:
  ...

with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile as stream:
  ...
```

Qual é a diferença entre utilizar cada uma dessas soluções? Existem outras formas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observando a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) referente ao módulo tempfile é possível sanar algumas de suas dúvidas.
Essa biblioteca é usada para a criação de arquivos e diretórios temporários, e para usos simples a diferenciação entre seus métodos a nível detalhado não é tão necessária. Contudo elas existem a nível de sistema operacional, como explico abaixo:

- `tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode, buffering, encoding, newline, suffix, prefixe, dir)`:

  - Esse método retorna um objeto *file-like* que pode ser usado como área de armazenamento. Agora olhando pelo lado do sistema operacional baseado em Unix, a entrada de diretório para o arquivo não é criada ou se é, é removida imediatamente após a criação do arquivo.
- `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode, buffering, encoding, newline, suffix, prefix, dir, delete)`:

  - Esse aqui, funciona da mesma forma do `TemporaryFile()`, com uma exceção, o arquivo terá um nome visível no sistema de arquivos(no Unix a entrada do diretório não é desvinculada). E esse nome pode ser descoberto com o atributo `name()` do objeto.
- `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size, mode, buffering, encoding, newline, suffix, prefix, dir)`:

  - Repare que nesse caso até um parâmetro é incrementado, ele tem o funcionamento igual ao `TemporaryFile()` com a exceção de que os dados são armazenados na memória até seu tamanho exceder o max_size, ou até o método `fileno()` for chamado, e então seu funcionamento segue igual ao do `TemporaryFile()`.
- `io.BytesIO()`:

  - Retorna um objeto parecido com um arquivo na memória que não altera as novas linhas e é semelhante ao open (filename, "wb"). Lida com strings `byte ()`.
- `io.stringIO()`:

  - Retorna um objeto semelhante a um arquivo na memória que altera novas linhas e é semelhante ao open(filename, "w"). Ele lida com strings `unicode ()`.

Espero que tenha esclarecido alguma de suas dúvidas. Muito do que foi dito, foi encontrado na documentação que eu linkei acima. Abraços!

Comment: Sim, foi bem útil. Só para esclarecer, a ideia da pergunta era justamente dispor desse conteúdo, mesmo que resumido, em português. Eu já sabia as diferenças, mas agora temos uma referência inicial para utilizarmos de referência :D

Comment: Ótimo jeito de impulsionar a comunidade !